# Working with system icons in C# application

Tags: windows, icons

Where can I find all system icons used in Windows XP/Vista/7? Is it possible?

I tried using [SHGetStockIconInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it returns only some icons.

Comment: You tagged c#, #.net, what does it has to do with C# and .NET.. An what are the search terms you used in Google? And a +1 for @DanielA.White

Comment: Uhh, which icon does `SHGetStockIconInfo` not have? That's the standard way of doing it.

Comment: it does not contains for example, network icon.

Comment: @The Mask for the network one look at my answer and install the VS2010 icons. The network one is located in: `_Common Elements\Objects\network.png`.  Not sure why the downvotes either but maybe because your original question was worded poorly.  I understood what you wanted though ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Windows 7 you can find many of the icons here:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\DDORes.dll
%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll
%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
```

I wouldn't recommend extracting them and using them though as that would be a copyright violation I think.

You can get a whole bunch of windows images within Visual Studio as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx

> The Visual Studio 2010 Image Library contains application images that
>   appear in Microsoft Windows, the Office system, Microsoft Visual
>   Studio, and other Microsoft software. You can use this set of over
>   1,000 images to create applications that look visually consistent with
>   Microsoft software.

**EDIT:**

Requested Visual Studio 2008 version:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582(v=vs.90).aspx

And for completeness the Visual Studio 2005 version:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Exactly it! Thanks. I'II try to extract the icons from dll. :)

Comment: @The Mask No no no... see my other comment, don't extract it look at the VS2010 icon pack that I linked.

Comment: um,is there equivalent in VS08?

Comment: @The Mask yes I have updated my answer with 2008 and 2005 info.

Answer (score 7):

Without specifying exactly which icons you're talking about, there is a [SystemIcons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx) class in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

Comment: I get the error: "The type or namespace 'SystemIcons' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'"


I already added the reference for System.Drawing.